# MouseListener on JFrame never being called

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, mouselistener

I'm trying to use a MouseListener to see when something is clicked in my JFrame, but none of the events (mouseClicked, mouseEntered, etc) are ever called. I'm using a Canvas to draw the game onto the JFrame and I'm wondering if that could be the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I was following [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jframe/create-jframe-window-with-mouse-event-handling/) tutorial and my code looks almost exactly the same.

Here's my JFrame class:

```
public class Display extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    public static final int CARD_SIZE = 100;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 25;
    public static final int TITLE_SIZE = 50;

    private JFrame frame;
    private MyCanvas canvas;

    public Display (int r, int c, Card[][] b) {
        width = c*CARD_SIZE + (c+2)*BUFFER_SIZE;
        System.out.println(width);
        height = r*CARD_SIZE + (r+1)*BUFFER_SIZE + TITLE_SIZE*2;
        System.out.println(height);
        frame = new JFrame("Matching Game");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        frame.addMouseListener(this);

        canvas = new MyCanvas(b);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered frame at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Exited frame at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Released at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary thing you were doing wrong was to extend JFrame and also create an explicit instance of one. Do it as follows.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Display  implements MouseListener {
    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    public static final int CARD_SIZE = 100;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 25;
    public static final int TITLE_SIZE = 50;

    private JPanel canvas;
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display(3,3,new int[3][3]);

    }

    public Display (int r, int c, int[][] b) {
        width = c*CARD_SIZE + (c+2)*BUFFER_SIZE;
        System.out.println(width);
        height = r*CARD_SIZE + (r+1)*BUFFER_SIZE + TITLE_SIZE*2;
        System.out.println(height);
        frame = new JFrame("Matching Game");
//        frame.setLayout(null);
//        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        frame.addMouseListener(this);

        canvas = new JPanel();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered frame at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Exited frame at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Released at X: " + e.getX() + " - Y: " + e.getY());
    }
}
```

Points to consider

- don't extend JFrame, just use an instance.
- Canvas is old.  I recommend using a JPanel to hold the components and/or painting
- `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` centers your frame on the screen.
- Since I don't have the `Card` class I used `int[][]` to demonstrate this.
- Anything else I did, check out the API documentation for explanations.

For more on GUI's, etc, check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Thank you! I implemented your suggestions and the MouseListener works now:) However, I was wondering how to paint using JPanel. All of the tutorials I have found have the class extending JPanel and then overriding the paintComponent method, but when I do this the MouseListener no longer works.

Comment: Add the mouse listener to the JPanel and not the Frame.  It will work.  I have done it many times.  And consider writing an inner class for your mouseListener.  Then extend MouseAdapter.  It has empty methods of the mouse interfaces so you only need to override the ones you want to use.